# Movie with a girl and her unipeg (winged unicorn) spirit animal

Tags: story-identification, movie, unicorns

Wife been bugging me to ask someone about and I have never heard of it.

She's talking about some animated movie with a unipeg (or winged unicorn) that grew up in a Pegasus group or family and is kind of an outcast. There's this human girl or princess that befriends the unipeg but can also hear its thoughts. Anyway, the girl has to choose a spirit animal at some point, but none of the spirit animals will befriend her, so she makes the unipeg her spirit animal.

I'm guessing she saw this as a kid so early 90s. Google has found me nothing (it's not *Unico* or *The Last Unicorn*).

Comment: These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: There might help; https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WingedUnicorn / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winged_unicorn#In_popular_culture

Comment: She thinks it was a movie but that princess gwenevere seems to kinda sound familiar especially it being in 1995 which would put her in that age range. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 5):

This is [indeed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191894/unipeg-spirit-animal-movie#comment525238_191894) *Princess Gwenevere and the Jewel Riders* (1995); more precisely, the glittery-to-a-shame pilot episode, which lasted 44 minutes, hence why your wife could've mistaken it for a movie.

The episode is on YouTube (see below), with the corresponding timestamps and screenshots in case the link goes dead:

- 7'35: the unipeg Sunstar grew up in a unicorn family, but can't play unicornball with them because she keeps on stumbling on her wings when running. [The others mock her](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU84i.png) and taunt her into trying to fly. [Epic fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybdiw.png);
- the titular Princess Gwenevere befriends Sunstar. You can see [her hearing the unipeg's fear of jumping/flying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Cc0.jpg) at 33'59;
- later, the Princess has to bond with an animal, but [the "bonding stone" doesn't react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es8QI.jpg) to any of the animal candidates (38'40);
- the unipeg had gone back to live with her family, but she's back and the two of them bond (40'34). [The stone even gives them matching outfits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8IcN.png).

Comment: Now if you excuse me I have to go read a dark, brooding Batman comic to wash off all that glitter from my eyes

Comment: Not just any Batman either. Like Frank Miller Batman